# Is there a handler for the django logger that creates github issues?

Tags: django, logging, github-api

Is there a handler for the django logger that creates an issue on github when a log entry is created? If there's not, how hard would it be to create one?

Comment: http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#topic-logging-parts-handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete "batteries included" answer, but, it will get you there with a little effort of your own.

1. Create a [custom logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/)
2. Have that custom logger create issues on github (I've used the below script)

Script for creating Github Issues:

```
import json
import requests

def make_issue(title, body=None, assignee=None, milestone=None, labels=None):
    '''Create an issue on github.com using the given parameters.'''
    # Authentication for user filing issue (must have read/write access to
    # repository to add issue to)
    username = 'CHANGEME'
    password = 'CHANGEME'
    # The repository to add this issue to
    repo_owner = 'CHANGEME'
    repo_name = 'CHANGEME'
    # Our url to create issues via POST
    url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/%s/%s/issues' % (repo_owner, repo_name)
    # Create an authenticated session to create the issue
    session = requests.session(auth=(username, password))
    # Create our issue
    issue = {'title': title,
             'body': body,
             'assignee': assignee,
             'milestone': milestone,
             'labels': labels}
    # Add the issue to our repository
    r = session.post(url, json.dumps(issue))
    if r.status_code == 201:
        print 'Successfully created Issue "%s"' % title
    else:
        print 'Could not create Issue "%s"' % title
        print 'Response:', r.content

make_issue('Issue Title', 'Body text', 'assigned_user', 3, ['bug'])
```